# Google Cloud Compute Engine ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Wordpress site set up on Google Cloud Compute, it was working fine until the SSL expired I tried to reinstall it but now I'm getting ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when accessing the site.

Now I'm getting This site can’t be reached

And when I run systemctl status apache2.service

```
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─forking.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-07-17 11:17:43 UTC; 16s ago
  Process: 1714 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1695 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 1798 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Comment: Check the Apache log files for warning and error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new VM instance from a snapshot. Not sure what was going on.